# Its reaonable don't store passwords for users in web local database?

Tags: security, authentication, passwords

Question for web developers, is it reasonable this design approach for authentification ?

I create a web and i don't store in my database any password for user profile. I just allow google or facebook logins via authentification tokens to assign user permissions and login check in my web.

With this approach, my web cannot ever be password stolen, because i don't have anyone. Obviously i must trust in google or facebook login systems, but i'm sure they protect their system than i my own.

Any suggestions or comments ?

Comment: It is completely your call if this approach works for your site. Note that site you are using right now consider this approach acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, storing passwords in a database controlled by you is ok. If you will decide to follow this way, please note that they are not stored in plain text. Also using 3rd party auth can allow to move faster with your prototyping.

## Storing the passwords locally has a few interesting moments you should be aware about

Usually database only stores a hash of a password, so even somebody has stolen a hash, they still do not know the actual password. [Password verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification) computes the hash of a password and compares that to the value stored in your db.

Another thing is that [hashes are salted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). They are slightly modified so attackers can't use precomputed tables for existing hash functions.

## Storing passwords locally requires you to implement related user flows

You'll have to implement code for password change, 'forgotten password', etc rather than focusing on your application code.

Major sites often allow multiple options (e.g. I can register via facebook/google or my e-mail + password).

In some domains people don't use Facebook auth (e.g. most of the security concerned geeks I know don't even have Facebook account).